# How can I use scanf to input coordinates and also a character if needed within this function

Tags: c

How can I have player one input coordinates (x,y)  (1,2) while also being able to have the option to input a character such as 'c' or 's'?

I can change x to char and then use %c for the first input and then have if (x =='1') x = 1 and so on, but it still will give me segmentation fault because it needs to scan something in for y. How can I fix this?

`matrix[][]` is a global char 2d array.

```
void updateTablePlayer1(void) 
{

    int  y, x;


    printf ("Enter a command for player 1 ([row,col], c, s, p):");
    scanf ("%d,%d", &x, &y);

    x--;
    y--;

    if (matrix[x][y]!= ' ')
    {
        printf ("Invalid selection\n");
        updateTablePlayer1();   
    {

    else if (x == 'c')
    {
        createClearTable();
        displayTable();
        updateTablePlayer1();
    }

    else if (x == 's')
    {
        displayTable();
        updateTablePlayer1();
    }

    else if (x == 'p')
    {
        displayTableImage();
        updateTablePlayer1();
    }

    else
        matrix[x][y] = 'X';


    }
```

Comment: Use the return value from `scanf`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a place call `scanf()`-land that is evil, surround by sharks and crawling with snakes.  Tortured sad code bodies are littered about.

There is a happier place called `fgets()`-land.  It has a few bumps and pitfalls, but is much safer - code with long old grey beards live there.

---

Step 1: flush the output to insure buffering does not prevent it from being shown *after* input

```
printf ("Enter a command for player 1 ([row,col], c, s, p):");
fflush(stdout);
```

Step 2: Read the line

```
// scanf ("%d,%d", &x, &y);
char buffer[80];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) Handle_input_closed();
```

Step 3: Parse the input.  Always check for errors.

```
 int x,y;
 char command;
 if (sscanf(buffer, "%d,%d", &x, &y) == 2) {
   Do_xy_Stuff();
 }

 else if (sscanf(buffer, " %c", &command) == 1) {
   if (command == 'c') Do_c_Stuff();
   else if (command == 's') Do_s_Stuff();
   else if (command == 'p') Do_p_Stuff();
   else Complain_about_bad_input();

 } else {
   Complain_about_bad_input();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `scanf` call is doing two things: reading in some input, and interpreting it as numbers. Separate these two things: read in a string, and then interpret it.

It is probably better to use `fgets` rather than `scanf` for reading in the string. When your input looks like it contains numbers, you could use `sscanf` to decode them.